# How to find and replace line in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to find the line starting with a string and replace the entire line using the shell command.
Example :
content of the file: Enableuserlogin    Yes
search word : Enableuserlogin
replace with : Enableuserlogin No

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you use `grep` , `sed` ,... etc.  ?

Comment: I have tried with sed and the command sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/^Enableuserlogin.*/Enableuserlogin  No/' config_filename". Just wanted to know if any other way